# Which western communist parties use crypto for donations?

Tags: communism, socialism, campaign-finance, cryptocurrency

Being aware of Russia's political scene, I [noticed](https://avtonom.org/pages/donate) that some Communist organizations (specifically Anarcho-Communists) use cryptocurrencies for donations.

I noticed that a lot of Western Communist reject Cryptocurrency as a way of financing themselves.

Reasons can vary as to why.

Are there any Western Communist parties or organizations that use Cryptocurrencies for donations or campaigns?

Comment: Why is it "weird" for leftists to reject cryptocurrency? [It's notorious for its massive carbon footprint](https://www.reuters.com/technology/how-big-is-bitcoins-carbon-footprint-2021-05-13/), and leftists tend to be more environmentally-conscious.

Comment: "Why is it "weird" for leftists to reject cryptocurrency?" Because some use many other monetary ways of financing themselves like Patreon, bank transfers or PayPal despite fighting for a "moneyless" society. 
https://www.cpusa.org/donate/

Better wording would be to pretend to be more pro-environment.
It frankly goes away very quickly once they are in power. You would also think if we accepted that argument, that they would be against massive money-printing if  CO2 was that big of an issue. 
Also riots tend to not be that environmentally healthy.

Comment: CPUSA is fighting for a "moneyless society" probably to the same extent that the USSR did. I don't see CPUSA mention "money" at all in https://www.cpusa.org/party_info/cpusa-constitution/ so the elimination thereof doesn't seem a core concern for them.

Comment: Communism is a hypothetical economic system of a classless moneyless society. The party wants to establish Communism in both program and name. 
And yes the USSR tried to establish Communism. 

"are essential steps toward our ultimate goal of the revolutionary transformation of society and the economy, toward socialism and then communism"
https://cpusa.org/party_info/party-program/

Comment: This stream of "crypto questions" is weird at best. As long as they are easily convertible to cash, there is no reason to refuse any kind of asset, be it cryptocurrency, gold, whatever. So the answer would be most likely "all of them." This is like asking which organizations accept $100 notes when donating cash.

Comment: @F1Krazy Well firstly its a great way of easily and fast to get money and if you use Monero you can easily trade it for rather illegal services.
If enviroment was such a great concern for certain leftist, they wouldn't support enviromentally damaging things like for example riots or China.

https://www.cpusa.org/?ssearch=china&fq=any&sort=score&order=desc&submit=Submit

https://www.aa.com.tr/en/europe/radical-leftist-militants-riot-in-east-germany/2913906

Answer (score 11):

As a rule, Communists have no reservations of using capitalist infrastructure to combat the rule of capital. In this case, using crypto is a reasonable, pragmatic choice for these very small unaligned organizations of just a few people.

Western leftists are a part of Western political system so it is important for them to send the right signals about environmental consciousness. Whereas, for the Russian grassroots leftists, the aim is power. They could enforce all kinds of policies, including banning (or indeed encouraging) crypto, after they come to power, but this is irrelevant for the process of gaining it.

Comment: Fair point (+1). One could add that the CCP is apparently trying to ban crypto mining https://twitter.com/SCMPNews/status/1612416970657337345?lang=en and even transactions https://www.npr.org/2021/09/24/1040381774/china-cryptocurrency-transactions-illegal-bitcoin The latter seems to be in the name of ensuring financial stability.

Comment: One additional point. In popular culture in the "west", cryptocurrency is perceived as a highly speculative investment opportunity instead of an alternative payment method. There are obvious reservations to leftists engaging in speculative finance.

Comment: Communists did not have any reservations robbing Russian banks for cash a hundred years back, and they will only praise turning speculative crypto money into good communist funding.

Comment: @alamar are you talking about the non-communist "communist party" or the same kinds of anarcho-communists mentioned in the question?

Comment: also the current russian ones may not have a choice due to sanctions. They can take crypto (useful) or rubles (worthless and help Putin) or nothing else (due to sanctions)

Comment: @user253751 More accurate to say is:  the current Russian ones may not have a choice due to being blacklisted by the main oligarch-controlled banks. 

Funny how crypto separates those repressed by the government with those who are not. 
Same as in the west.

Comment: @Apoliticalboy Putin and the oligarchs benefit when people have rubles, so I doubt they have a problem with it.

Comment: @user253751 Not if those people (mainly opposition) have this money to undermine their regime. 
I don't think you understand how power politics work.

Comment: @Apoliticalboy Rubles are worthless toilet paper. The oligarchs have the dollars and the euros which actually matter. Meanwhile the more rubles an opposition group has the less dollars and euros it has which is bad for it.

Comment: You can go to exchange booth with your roubles and get dollars if you like. I think it also applies to underground communists.